# testing service with mockito and spring

Tags: java, spring, testing, mockito, dto

Trying to test services methods. 
This is method what I want to test:

```
    @Override
public ReportListDto retrieveAllReportsList() {
    List<ReportDto> reportDtos = reportMapper.toDtos(reportRepository.findAll());

    return new ReportListDtoBuilder().reportsDto(reportDtos).build();
}
```

This is my test method (I got it from some tutorial):

```
@Test
public void testRetrieveAllReportList() throws Exception {
    List<Report> expected = new ArrayList<>();
    when(reportRepositoryMock.findAll()).thenReturn(expected);

    ReportListDto actual = reportService.retrieveAllReportsList();

    verify(reportRepositoryMock, times(1)).findAll();
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(reportRepositoryMock);

    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

But tutorial does not use DTO models. So last asert has expected `List<Report>` object and actual `ReportListDto` object.

This is my `ReportListDto`:

```
public class ReportListDto implements Serializable {
    private List<ReportDto> reports = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<ReportDto> getReports() {
        return reports;
    }

    public void setReports(List<ReportDto> reports) {
        this.reports = reports;
    }
}
```

How can I test service what use dto mapper?

Comment: Make the mock DAO return more than 0 Report. And based on the list of reports that the DAO returns, check that the ReportListDto returned by the service contains the correct number of ReportDtos, in the right order, and containing the right values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement `equals` on your `ReportListDTO` object, `assertEquals` will use it.

Many IDEs like intelliJ or Eclipse can do that for you... otherwise, you could write something like:

```
 @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        ReportListDto that = (ReportListDto) o;

        return reports != null ? reports.equals(that.reports) : that.reports == null;

    }
```